# Unity 5 with Vufloria: An error occured while trying to enable Vufloria play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop a basic augmented reality app on Unity 5 (32 bit software) on Vufloria and have everything setup.

Unfortunately, I am getting the error:

"An error occured while trying to enable Vufloria play mode"

[image]

Code for Webcam Profile (profiles.xml) (Levono EasyCamera added at the end of XML file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profiles>
    <!-- this profile will be used if no specific profile could be found -->
    <default>
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
            <!-- <resampledTextureHeight>480</resampledTextureHeight> -->
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
            <!-- <resampledTextureHeight>480</resampledTextureHeight> -->
        </osx>
    </default>
    <!-- these are examples of configured web cam profiles. -->
    <!-- please enter the name of your camera as shown in the popup dialog. -->
    <!-- Unity does not guarantee to deliver a webcam texture in the requested size,
        therefore it may need to be resampled to the required size.
        If no resampledTextureHeight is specified, the aspect ratio will be kept when resampling is done.
        Specifying a resampledTextureHeight will enforce a certain aspect ratio, even if it's different from the
        created web cam texture. This can be used to fixe cases where the webcam textue is distorted.
        Please note that in Unity 4.5 on Mac, different web cam models that deliver different aspect ratios 
        identify themselves with the same name (e.g. Logitech C910 and C920 are both just 'Logitech Camera') -->
    <webcam deviceName="Built-in iSight">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Integrated Camera">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
    <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Microsoft® LifeCam HD-6000 for Notebooks">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="HD Pro Webcam C920">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Logitech Camera">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Logitech Webcam Pro 9000">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>

    <webcam deviceName="Logitech HD Webcam C270">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Microsoft LifeCam HD-6000">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)">
        <windows>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </windows>
        <osx>
            <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
            <requestedTextureWidth>1280</requestedTextureWidth>
            <requestedTextureHeight>720</requestedTextureHeight>
            <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
            <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        </osx>
    </webcam>
    <webcam deviceName="Lenovo EasyCamera">
    <windows>
        <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
        <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
        <requestedTextureHeight>480</requestedTextureHeight>
        <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
        <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        <resampledTextureHeight>480</resampledTextureHeight>
    </windows>
    <osx>
        <!-- size of the web cam texture requested from Unity -->
        <requestedTextureWidth>640</requestedTextureWidth>
        <requestedTextureHeight>360</requestedTextureHeight>
        <!-- size of the texture Unity's web cam texture will be rescaled to -->
        <resampledTextureWidth>640</resampledTextureWidth>
        <resampledTextureHeight>360</resampledTextureHeight>
    </osx>
</webcam>

</profiles>
```

Settings:

[image]

Scene:

[image]

This is the computer I am using:

Lenovo Yoga (webcam: Lenovo EasyCamera)

Windows 10 (64 bit)

Unity 5.3.1f1 (32 bit)  [can switch to Unity 5.3.0f4 (64-bit)]

Vufloria 5